# object 'new HttpResponseMessage()' is not disposed along all exception paths

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, dispose, httpresponsemessage

I have tired using statement after going through the links in stackoverflow  but still couldnt figure the exact solution.

```
 using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(textAsBytes))
            {
                using (HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    Content = new StreamContent(stream)
                })
                {
                    httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                    {
                        FileName = "main-theme.scss"
                    };
                    httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/css");

                    ResponseMessageResult responseMessageResult = ResponseMessage(httpResponseMessage);
                    return responseMessageResult;
                }
            }
```

getting the following error

**CA2000    In method 'GetStyleSheet()', object 'new HttpResponseMessage()' is not disposed along all exception paths. Call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'new HttpResponseMessage()' before all references to it are out of scope.**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when creating the `HttpResponseMessage` you use a property initializer in addition to the constructor:

```
using (HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
  Content = new StreamContent(stream)
})
{
  // ...
}
```

This leads to a code similar to the following is generated:

```
var httpRepsonseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
httpResponseMessage.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
try
{
   // ...
}
finally
{
  httpResponseMessage.Dispose();
}
```

As you can see, `httpResponseMessage` will not be disposed if something goes wrong when creating the StreamContent and assigning it.

In order to solve this, move the assignment into the using block:

```
using (HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK))
{
  httpResponseMessage.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
  // ...
}
```

This way, the disposal takes place even if there is a problem when assigning the content.